# Given a list of filenames (without paths), find the files within multiple subdirectories and copy those files to a destination folder

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

I need a way to take a .txt or .csv list of filenames as a source, search through a directory, under which there are multiple subdirectories (though not more than 2-3 levels), and copy the found files to a destination folder. I've not had success with this:

```
for file in `cat ~/Desktop/filelist.txt`; do cp "$file" ~/Desktop; done
```

...and rsync is failing me as well. I know there are multiple similar questions like this on here already, but I'm not finding a solution that works for me.

Comment: You have to mark code with the editors `{}`-Button, else you experience surprises. Look at the preview!

Answer (score 1):

If you have to *search*, you will might want to use `find` at some point. Here is a rough sketch:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for fileName in $(cat ~/Desktop/filelist.txt)
do
  find \
    /full/path/to/directory/to/search \
    -maxdepth 3 \
    -name "$fileName" \
    -exec mv {} /full/path/to/destinationDirectory/ \;
done
```

The `IFS=$'\n'` part and all the double quotes are there so that the script works when some of the files in the list have spaces in their names. The backslashes are there to ignore line breaks (it's one long `find` command inside the loop).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I'm embarrassed to admit that my first few failed tries may have had to do with incorrect directory paths. I just got it running and the number of files in the list is rather long; I'm thinking this will take many hours to finish. Is there any way to make the script more efficient? Also, can you explain why the dollar sign/parens is there, instead of the single quotes around cat and filename?